# Difference Between iOS Push Notifications and Remote Notifications?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

In Xcode under app capabilities there is an option to turn on Push Notifications. Under Background Modes there is also an option to turn on Remote Notifications. What is the difference? Pros/Cons?

Do I still set up a push certificate for remote notifications?

Comment: remote notif and push notif are same. Remote notif and local notif are different.

Comment: Do I need to have both remote and push notifications enabled for it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote notifications is a special (and rather poorly named) background mode that allows the app to download content in response to a push notification.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> The app wants to start downloading content when a push notification
>   arrives. Use this notification to minimize the delay in showing
>   content related to the push notification.

Normal push notifications will not require this permission, but adding this mode allows additional functionality for push notifications.

And yes, you will still require push certificates even with this background mode enabled.

Comment: So if a user had set "Allow Notifications" for the app in Settings to Off, can Remote Notifications still work?

Comment: You should post that as a new question, or just try it.